# Get display name for logical name

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have list of logical names for an entity for which I need to retreive the displayname.

For eg I have

```
List<string> _list=new List<string>();
_list.Add("address_City")
_list.Add("first_name")
```

The display names for them are **Address City** and **First Name**

```
RetrieveEntityRequest req = new RetrieveEntityRequest();
req.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
req.LogicalName = "account";
req.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes;

RetrieveEntityResponse resp = (RetrieveEntityResponse)_orgService.Execute(req);

for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < resp.EntityMetadata.Attributes.ToList().Count; iCnt++)
{
    if(resp.EntityMetadata.Attributes.ToList()[iCnt].DisplayName.LocalizedLabels.Count>0)
    {
        string displayName = resp.EntityMetadata.Attributes.ToList()[iCnt].DisplayName.LocalizedLabels[0].Label;
        string logicalName = resp.EntityMetadata.Attributes.ToList()[iCnt].LogicalName;

    }
}
```

This code retrieves all the record .Is there a way to create some custom query where I can just pass this `List<string>` and retrieve there display names?

Comment: You should be able to check against the logical name within the for loop and should be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Linq would work great.  Just taking your list of logical names and returning a list of display names would look like this:

```
List<string> _list = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "address_City",
                        "first_name"
                    };

List<string> _displayList = new List<string>();

if (entityMetaData.Attributes.Any())
{
    _displayList.AddRange(from lName in _list 
                          select (entityMetaData.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LogicalName.Equals(lName))) 
                          into attribute 
                          where attribute.DisplayName.UserLocalizedLabel != null 
                          select attribute.DisplayName.UserLocalizedLabel.Label);
}
```

You could use the same logic when returning a dictionary with the logicalName and displayName.  Your response from the entity request already has all the metadata, so you don't lose much time at all sifting through that data and getting what you want.